# Received ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: message when trying to download dbus-python for Python 3.9.x

Tags: python, package

I'm trying to get the dbus-python package for a project I'm doing. However, every single time the download errors out with the message below. I know that it tells me that "This version of the AC_PYTHON_DEVEL macro
doesn't work properly with versions of Python before
2.1.0. You may need to re-run configure, setting the
variables PYTHON_CPPFLAGS, PYTHON_LIBS, PYTHON_SITE_PKG,
PYTHON_EXTRA_LIBS and PYTHON_EXTRA_LDFLAGS by hand.
Moreover, to disable this check, set PYTHON_NOVERSIONCHECK
to something else than an empty string." but I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated. The entire message is copied below. I'm programming on a Macbook Pro using Pycharm.

```
Collecting dbus-python
  Using cached dbus-python-1.2.16.tar.gz (576 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dbus-python, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dbus-python
    Running setup.py install for dbus-python: started
    Running setup.py install for dbus-python: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: '/Users/nicole/PycharmProjects/NASA Notifier /venv/bin/python' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-record-xigztmmr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '/Users/nicole/PycharmProjects/NASA Notifier /venv/include/site/python3.9/dbus-python'
         cwd: /private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/
    Complete output (139 lines):
    running install
    running build
    creating /private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/build
    creating /private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
    checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables...
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking minix/config.h usability... no
    checking minix/config.h presence... no
    checking for minix/config.h... no
    checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether build environment is sane... yes
    checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/build-aux/install-sh -c -d
    checking for gawk... no
    checking for mawk... no
    checking for nawk... no
    checking for awk... awk
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
    checking whether UID '501' is supported by ustar format... yes
    checking whether GID '20' is supported by ustar format... yes
    checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
    checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
    checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
    checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
    checking for native Windows host... no
    checking how to print strings... printf
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
    checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
    checking for ld used by gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld
    checking if the linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
    checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
    checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
    checking whether ln -s works... yes
    checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 786432
    checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0 file names to x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
    checking for /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
    checking for objdump... objdump
    checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
    checking for dlltool... no
    checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for archiver @FILE support... no
    checking for strip... strip
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
    checking for sysroot... no
    checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
    checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
    checking for mt... no
    checking if : is a manifest tool... no
    checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
    checking for nmedit... nmedit
    checking for lipo... lipo
    checking for otool... otool
    checking for otool64... no
    checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
    checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
    checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
    checking for dlfcn.h... yes
    checking for objdir... .libs
    checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
    checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
    checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
    checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
    checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
    checking whether the gcc linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
    checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin20.3.0 dyld
    checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
    checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... no
    checking for inline... inline
    checking for gawk... (cached) awk
    checking for python... /Users/nicole/PycharmProjects/NASA Notifier /venv/bin/python
    checking for a version of Python >= '2.1.0'... /private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/configure: line 12491: /Users/nicole/PycharmProjects/NASA: No such file or directory
    no
    configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9':
    configure: error:
    This version of the AC_PYTHON_DEVEL macro
    doesn't work properly with versions of Python before
    2.1.0. You may need to re-run configure, setting the
    variables PYTHON_CPPFLAGS, PYTHON_LIBS, PYTHON_SITE_PKG,
    PYTHON_EXTRA_LIBS and PYTHON_EXTRA_LDFLAGS by hand.
    Moreover, to disable this check, set PYTHON_NOVERSIONCHECK
    to something else than an empty string.
    
    See `config.log' for more details
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/setup.py", line 85, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/Users/nicole/PycharmProjects/NASA Notifier /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/nicole/PycharmProjects/NASA Notifier /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/install.py", line 546, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/setup.py", line 56, in run
        subprocess.check_call([
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/configure', '--disable-maintainer-mode', 'PYTHON=/Users/nicole/PycharmProjects/NASA Notifier /venv/bin/python', '--prefix=/private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/prefix']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: '/Users/nicole/PycharmProjects/NASA Notifier /venv/bin/python' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-install-daqlmzc5/dbus-python_4a7bcf7e6a2c47da8d3d0113cdab5868/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/br/9qyn_k6s7x771bs__199zp9w0000gn/T/pip-record-xigztmmr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '/Users/nicole/PycharmProjects/NASA Notifier /venv/include/site/python3.9/dbus-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: what system do you use? Maybe there is this module in system repositorium - ie. on Linux Mint I can use `apt` to see precompiled `python3-dbus`

Comment: on Linux/Unix system you can try `export PYTHON_NOVERSIONCHECK=True` before installing